# Is there any simple way to parse a SpannableStringBuilder as XML?

Tags: android, xml, spannablestring

I am trying to convert a rich text field to an XML file for export; it seems quite a complicated process; trying to properly close StyleSpans, for example turning a SpannableStringBuilder with the following span layout:

`<bold>some text<italics>more text</bold>even more text</italics>`

into proper xml:

`<bold>some text<italics>more text</italics></bold><italics>even more text</italics>`

Is there any library or function that can do the necessary iterations for me or some code example that will close spans properly without me having to start from scratch?